# Openconnect problems on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: configuration, vpn, openvpn, vpnc

Getting problems on the Ubuntu 11.04 for openconnect... the failure after connecting says:

```
Got CONNECT response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
CSTP connected. DPD 30, Keepalive 20
Connected tun0 as 172.21.246.21, using SSL
DTLS handshake failed: 2
```

I thought it is a kernel fault so I updated to 12.04 which didn't change the message. It could be that the vpnc-script has the problem. Is there any workaround for this issue ?

I already got the vpnc package and downloaded the **/etc/vpnc/vpnc-script**

Comment: Did you test whether the connection actually works? What vpnc-script are you using (i had to install the `vpnc` package to get `/etc/vpnc/vpnc-script`)?

Answer (score 2):

Is this bug your problem?  I ran into this and ended up doing a distribution upgrade to 12.10 to get passed it...

[Can’t connect to VPN from GNOME Shell](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/985788)

It's been a while since this happened and I don't entirely recall what I ran into, but your problem seems very familiar to me.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have any relation to the kernel. The last line says DTLS handshake procedure has failed. So I think you need to turn on verbose logs of your client and see why handshake fails. The problem comes from TLS/SSL library.

Answer (score 0):

[This seems to be a workaround](http://aptosid.com/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=8788&sid=6a9007adc7c91385fce220706a402b20#8788). I never tried it though.

> The LKML thread suggests replacing line 119 in vpnc-script with
>         Code:
>
> ```
> sed 's/cache//;s/metric \?[0-9]\+ [0-9]\+//g;s/hoplimit[0-9]\+//g;s/ipid 0x....//g'
> ```

Try your luck and if it works. Post the steps you followed as a answer for the others in the community

Comment: The link doesn't seem to apply to the OP's problem at all (different VPN client, different error message). Why do you think it will solve his problems?

Comment: unfortunately in line 119 is an if clause sth. like              if [ -r /etc/openwrt_release ] && [ -n "$OPENWRT_INTERFACE" ]; then
        . /etc/functions.sh                                                  I put it above otherwise doesnt make sense... but didn't work.... do u know which date the thread is.... I guess is an old one and the scriptline has already been changed....